# Android Scale, SDL2 Scale graphics

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, 2d, sdl-2

I'm porting a game to android using SDL2, I have a issue with the texture when I trying to show the texture in the screen it show but with a size that is little the size in pixel and using I believe that I must scale in order to fit dpi, could you tell how could I resolve it.